# MongoDB. Why requests by the index are performed so slowly?

Tags: mongodb

Need your help in the following things:

I have a MongoDB collection that includes more that 26 millions documents.
Document's structure is constant (pastebin.com/iBzW0Fkz)

The collection includes an index on the "users" field

```
db.conversations.getIndexes();
```

RESULT - pastebin.com/xHecpw00

All requests for field "users" are performed very slow (more than 100 ms)

```
db.getCollection('conversations').find({users: {$all: ["5942328", "9082468"]}});
```

EXPLAIN - pastebin.com/0C11Cr9F

```
db.getCollection('conversations').find({users: "9163099"});
```

EXPLAIN - pastebin.com/CmvuDf10

**The list of questions:**

1. Why requests by the index are performed so slowly?
2. How to warm up indexes after restarting of mongodb server or process? Touch() instruction is no longer available in WiredTiger engine.

Here it is an additional info

```
db.stats();
```

RESULT - pastebin.com/9JZF8ChQ

```
db.getCollection('conversations').stats();
```

RESULT - pastebin.com/17yV4Fsi

```
db.conversations.getIndexes();
```

RESULT - pastebin.com/xHecpw00

Info about the server:

**lscpu** - pastebin.com/k7wUE4gH

**lshw -short** - pastebin.com/w5XYuY3U

There is an assumption that read operation from HDD is a bottleneck and SSD may solve this issue, but there is no opportunity to test it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think the problem is that you have a lot of data.
2. Your index is on array field, which is not effecient because your index becomes very large as MongoDB indexes each value of the array, so you can query for individual items.

You may want to look into sharding to split your data across multiple instances, but note that you cannot pick [`users` field as shard key](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-multikey/)